# Does MassTransit have a WCF Inteface that a client/service can use?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf, masstransit

Does MassTransit support WCF? I searched their website but couldn't find any examples on whether you can or how to create a WCF client/service using MassTransit. If it can be done, can someone please provide an example? a tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WCF to create a public interface that bridges an external service to an internal message-based application, but WCF is not a supported transport for durable messaging.

This would be useful in a case where your internal system might become overloaded by an external service, and you need to buffer the ingestion of data via a SOAP-based WCF service. The WCF endpoint would send messages to a command queue to process the information asynchronously, preventing timeouts from being pushed back to the calling service.